# Adding order by to a cursor SQL server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have this query:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_ANSWER_GRID] 
   @league int,
   @league_survey_id int,
   @page_size int,
   @page_num int,
   @orderby varchar(50),
   @f_division_id int,
   @myf_group_id int,
   @searchname varchar(250)
AS
--These will be sproc params:
--declare @page_size int;
--declare @page_num int;
--declare @league_survey_id int;
--declare @orderby varchar(50);
--set @league_survey_id = 340;
--set @page_size=419;
--set @page_num=0;
--set @orderby = 'f_member_id';
----
declare @query varchar(max);
declare @joins varchar(max);
declare @groupaddon varchar(max);
declare @membersearchaddon varchar(max);
declare @questionid varchar(50);
declare @question varchar(50);
declare @question_type int;
declare @minrow int;
declare @maxrow int;
declare @i int;
if @myf_group_id= 0
    begin
        set @groupaddon = ''
    end
    else
        begin
            set @groupaddon = 'and f_group_id = ' + convert(varchar(50),@myf_group_id) + ''
        end
set @minrow = @page_size * @page_num;
if len(@searchname) = 0
    begin
        set @membersearchaddon = ''
    end
    else
        begin
            set @membersearchaddon = 'and str_last_name like ''' + convert(varchar(250),@searchname) + '%'''
        end
set @maxrow = ((@page_num + 1) * @page_size); 
-- one sec
set @i = 0;
set @query = 'select * from (select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ' + @orderby + ') as RANK from (select 
    a.f_member_id,a.f_member_id as bulk_f_member_id,a.f_member_id as p_member_id, 
    (   select max(ans.dte_added) 
        from tb_league_survey_answers ans with(nolock)          
                  where ans.f_member_id = a.f_member_id 
                  and ans.f_league_survey_id = ' + convert(varchar(50),@league_survey_id) + ') dte_added, 

    (   select top 1 ans.f_division_id
        from tb_league_survey_answers ans with(nolock)          
                  where ans.f_member_id = a.f_member_id 
                  and ans.f_division_id != 0
                  and ans.f_league_survey_id = ' + convert(varchar(50),@league_survey_id) + ') f_division_id, 

    (   select top 1 dues_collected.int_division_fees_collected
        from tb_league_dues_collected dues_collected with(nolock)
            inner join tb_league_dues l_dues with(nolock) on (dues_collected.f_dues_id = l_dues.p_dues_id)
                where dues_collected.f_league_id = ' + convert(varchar(50),@league) + '
                and l_dues.f_league_id = ' + convert(varchar(50),@league) + '
                and l_dues.bln_archived = 0
                and dues_collected.f_division_id = (select top 1 ans.f_division_id from tb_league_survey_answers ans with(nolock) where ans.f_member_id = a.f_member_id and ans.f_league_survey_id = ' + convert(varchar(50),@league_survey_id) + ' and ans.f_division_id !=0)
                and dues_collected.f_member_id = a.f_member_id
                order by l_dues.p_dues_id desc
                    ) int_division_fees_collected,

    (   select top 1 dues_collected.int_amount_collected
        from tb_league_dues_collected dues_collected with(nolock)
            inner join tb_league_dues l_dues with(nolock) on (dues_collected.f_dues_id = l_dues.p_dues_id)
                where dues_collected.f_league_id = ' + convert(varchar(50),@league) + '
                and l_dues.bln_archived = 0
                and l_dues.f_league_id = ' + convert(varchar(50),@league) + '
                and dues_collected.f_division_id = (select top 1 ans.f_division_id from tb_league_survey_answers ans with(nolock) where ans.f_member_id = a.f_member_id and ans.f_league_survey_id = ' + convert(varchar(50),@league_survey_id) + ' and ans.f_division_id !=0)
                and dues_collected.f_member_id = a.f_member_id
                order by l_dues.p_dues_id desc
                ) int_amount_collected,

    (   select top 1 dues_collected.bln_master_transaction
        from tb_league_dues_collected dues_collected with(nolock)
            inner join tb_league_dues l_dues with(nolock) on (dues_collected.f_dues_id = l_dues.p_dues_id)
                where dues_collected.f_league_id = ' + convert(varchar(50),@league) + '
                and l_dues.bln_archived = 0
                and l_dues.f_league_id = ' + convert(varchar(50),@league) + '
                and dues_collected.f_division_id = (select top 1 ans.f_division_id from tb_league_survey_answers ans with(nolock) where ans.f_member_id = a.f_member_id and ans.f_league_survey_id = ' + convert(varchar(50),@league_survey_id) + ' and ans.f_division_id !=0)
                and dues_collected.f_member_id = a.f_member_id
                order by l_dues.p_dues_id desc
                ) bln_master_transaction,

    (   select max(cast(bln_multiple_payments_order as int)) as bln_multiple_payments_order
            from tb_league_dues_collected with(nolock)
            where XID in (
                        select distinct(XID) as XID
                            from tb_league_dues_collected dues_collected with(nolock)
                            inner join tb_league_dues l_dues with(nolock) on (dues_collected.f_dues_id = l_dues.p_dues_id)
                            where dues_collected.f_league_id = ' + convert(varchar(50),@league) + '
                            and l_dues.bln_archived = 0
                            and l_dues.f_league_id = ' + convert(varchar(50),@league) + '
                            and dues_collected.f_division_id = (select top 1 ans.f_division_id from tb_league_survey_answers ans with(nolock) where ans.f_member_id = a.f_member_id and ans.f_league_survey_id = ' + convert(varchar(50),@league_survey_id) + ' and ans.f_division_id !=0)
                            and dues_collected.f_member_id = a.f_member_id
                        )
            ) bln_multiple_payments_order,

a.f_group_id,a.str_group_name,a.str_division,a.str_officer_title,a.p_group_membership_id,a.bln_participation_status,a.str_badge_id,a.master_first_name,a.master_last_name,a.master_email,a.str_phone_number,a.team_creator_id,a.team_admin_list,a.dte_user_birthday,a.str_email_current,a.str_first_name,a.str_middle_name,a.str_last_name,a.f_submember_of'
set @joins = ''
declare cur cursor local for 
    (
        select distinct convert(varchar(50), p_league_survey_question_id), str_question, str_question_type 
        from tb_league_survey_questions with(nolock) 
        where f_league_survey_id = @league_survey_id
    );
open cur
fetch next from cur into @questionid, @question, @question_type
while (@@fetch_status = 0)
begin
set @joins = @joins + '
left outer join tb_league_survey_answers q' + convert(varchar(50), @i)  + ' with(nolock) on q' + convert(varchar(50), @i) + '.f_league_survey_question_id = ' + @questionid + ' and q' + convert(varchar(50), @i)  + '.f_member_id = a.f_member_id'
if (@question_type <> 4)
begin
    set @query = @query + ', q' + convert(varchar(50), @i) + '.str_answer as [question' + @questionid + '] '
end else begin
    set @query = @query + ', qDiv' + convert(varchar(50), @i) + '.str_division as [question' + @questionid + '] '
    set @joins = @joins + '
left outer join tb_league_team_divisions qDiv' + convert(varchar(50), @i)  + ' with(nolock) on qDiv' + convert(varchar(50), @i) + '.p_division_id = convert(int, q' + convert(varchar(50), @i) + '.str_answer)'
end
--from tb_league_team_divisions where p_division_id = ' + convert(varchar(50), @divisionid) + ') 
fetch next from cur into @questionid, @question, @question_type
set @i = @i + 1;
end 
close cur
deallocate cur
set @query = @query + ' from vw_league_members a with(nolock) ' + @joins + ' WHERE exists 
    (
        select * 
        from tb_league_survey_answers ans with(nolock)  
        where ans.f_member_id = a.f_member_id 
        and a.f_league_id = <league_placeholder>
        and ans.f_league_survey_id = ' + convert(varchar(50),@league_survey_id) + '
        and ans.f_division_id = ' + convert(varchar(50),@f_division_id) + '     
        <group_placeholder>
        <membersearch_placeholder>
    )
) data ) dataouter where RANK > ' + convert(varchar(50), @minrow) + ' AND RANK <= ' + convert(varchar(50), @maxrow)
set @query = replace(@query, '<group_placeholder>', @groupaddon)
set @query = replace(@query, '<membersearch_placeholder>', @membersearchaddon)
set @query = replace(@query, '<league_placeholder>', @league)
--print @query;
execute(@query);
```

What I need to do is add an order by to this part of the t-sql

```
declare cur cursor local for 
    (
        select distinct convert(varchar(50), p_league_survey_question_id), str_question, str_question_type 
        from tb_league_survey_questions with(nolock) 
        where f_league_survey_id = @league_survey_id
    );
```

but I get

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SP_ANSWER_GRID, Line 119
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the parentheses

```
declare cur cursor local for 
        select distinct convert(varchar(50), p_league_survey_question_id), str_question, str_question_type 
        from tb_league_survey_questions with(nolock) 
        where f_league_survey_id = @league_survey_id
        order by 1
```

Comment: I did and now I get Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SP_ANSWER_GRID, Line 115
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Comment: @JeffShain Yes. The column you added as order by column must be included in the select list if you use distinct.

Comment: Makes perfect sense if you think about it. the value you use in order by could be different between rows that are merged to a single row by the distinct keyword.

Comment: How would SQL Server know by what value to order by?

Comment: Well I would explicitly state it. It's order by int_question_weight,p_league_survey_question_id which are two columns in that table.

Comment: Then those two column must be included in the column list if you want to use distinct.